# Route 53 AWS configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

The numerical IPv4 address for my EC2 instance works perfectly. However, when I create an A record for my domain to point to the IPv4 address browser returns "Cant find the server"

I have created a hosted zone In route53, under DNS management. My name server match the ones from the domain with the one in my hosted zone.

Not sure why my domain is not working but the IPv4 address is working fine.

Comment: Give us more data in order to help you

Comment: Can you resolve the ip for the domain and see whether it returns the one assigned to EC2 or not?

Comment: is the domain hosted as public?

Comment: @GowthamChand Yes its a public hosted zone.

Comment: @Ashan I don't understand what you are saying. Currently the IP for the domain points to an EC2 instance. The IP for the EC2 instance works.

Comment: @datelligence What specifically would you like to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so Route53 can be confusing for people who first start using domain names and dont' have a lot of experience with DNS. Let me walk through what you are seeing on the console:

1. When you registered your domain, it automatically created a "Hosted Zone" for you. When you click on Route53 and it shows you all your hosted zones, if you click on the one you're trying to forward, the NS records that show up to the right on the console *must match the ones that appear when you click on your domain*. If they don't match, no amount of forwarding will work.
2. If you created a new Hosted Zone, you may need to update the name servers on your domain. A common mistake is to open the hosted zone, and modify the NS entry in the hosted zone. This will not work. The NS record *forwards* to those name servers, it doesn't change the name servers of that hosted zone. The hosted zone will always have the same name servers.
3. Once you've successfully forwarded your name servers, an "NSLOOKUP" on your domain should return your name servers.

Once all that is set up, creating an A record within the hosted zone should now forward to your IP (or better yet, a load balancer URL).

To recap:

- Create a domain, which will automatically create a hosted zone.
- Create a new hosted zone (which is assigned 4 new name servers)
- Create an NS entry in the original hosted zone that points to the newly created hosted zone's name servers
- Create an A record in the new hosted zone to forward your domain